# Making the "Uninstall" command do the right thing for a Windows 8 application

Tags: windows-8, uninstallation

In the Windows 8 Start screen, I noticed that there is an **Uninstall** icon that appears at the bottom if you right-click on an app.  For the apps that I developed, if I click on the Uninstall icon, it opens the "Programs and Features" dialog.  Ideally it should instead directly launch my uninstaller.  Does anyone know how to do that?  Is there some registry key I need to set to associate Start Menu shortcuts with uninstallers?

I use various technologies to make my apps (e.g. Qt, C#, Visual Studio setup projects, NSIS).  On Windows 7 and below, my installers put shortcuts in the Start Menu.  On Windows 8, those shortcuts are displayed as a little square in the Start screen.  So that shortcut is the object I am right-clicking on.  Is there some way to add uninstall data to the shortcut file itself?

Comment: I think you'll find that if you do that on any app the same thing happens. In other words, your app is not unique in its behaviour.

Comment: So perhaps there is no hope.  I haven't found a 3rd party app that behaves nicely, but I tried clicking the "Uninstall" icons for Games, Camera, Music, and Video, and all of those provide a nicer user experience.

Comment: Windows Store apps allow direct uninstall from the Start menu. Desktop apps send you to Programs and Features.

Comment: What about desktop apps that are available on the windows store?

Comment: @AlexandreJasmin desktop apps on windows store aren't hosted on store, store redirects the user to developer website.

Comment: I would say that the uninstall does the acceptable thing. Let's take SQL server for instance, you select uninstall - which of the 8 or 9 uninstallers should it launch? At the end of the day you suggestion is optimal, but won't work in many cases so the solution we have is one that works everywhere, if not always optimally.

Comment: I'm sure that if Microsoft made it possible to customize right-click option for .LNK files on the start screen or some other mean of launching the uninstaller directly, a lot of Desktop apps could be updated to take advantage of it... But then again I don't even think a Desktop app can have live tiles so I wouldn't expect that to happen...

Comment: @AlexandreJasmin:  I guess if only half of the desktop apps took advantage of it, that could be more confusing to the user than if none of them took advantage of it.

Comment: It doesn't work even you put a .LNK file, MS only provides DELETE for .LNK file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tiles for desktop applications do not automatically uninstall like tiles for store applications. Choosing 'Uninstall' for a desktop applications tile launches the Add / Remove programs experience as you pointed out. This is by design.